# Trying to read xml element value in xsl

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I am new to [XSL](http://www.w3.org/Style/XSL/). I am trying to read values of XML elements using a XSL file. My XML file is like:

```
<PersonList>
  <Person>
    <Name>person1</Name>
    <Age>21</Age>
  </Person>
  <Person>
    <Name>person2</Name>
    <Age>21</Age>
  </Person>
</PersonList>
```

My XSL file is like:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns=...>
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" encoding="utf-8" omit-xml declaration="no" />
  <xsl template match="/">
    <PersonList>
      <xsl:for-each select="PersonList/Person">
        <Person>
          <xsl:for-each select="*">
            <xsl:variable name="elementName">
              <xsl:value-of select="name(.)" />
            </xsl:variable>
            <xsl:variable name="elementValue">
              ???
            </xsl:variable>
          </xsl:for-each>
        </Person>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </PersonList> 
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

How should I replace `???` to get the value of the element stored in the `elementName` variable. I tried the following three lines separately:

```
<xsl:value-of select="value(.)" /> 
<xsl:value-of select="value($elementName)" />
<xsl:value-of select="$elementName" />
```

but no luck. Please help!

Comment: Consider to post the XML result you want to create with XSLT for the XML input sample you have posted. It is difficult to tell from your XSLT sample what you want to achieve as it has syntax errors like `xsl template` and logical flaws like an empty `for-each` body or using `name(.)` where the context node is the root node.

Comment: I have corrected the xsl. Please consider now. I want to get values Person1, 21, Person2, 21 in elementValue variable in a loop.

Comment: You should really read up on the difference between _pull_ processing (which you are doing) and _push_ style.  For a task like this, push-style, where you use templates and apply-templates, is much more natural and matches the way the XSL processor works.  It looks like you are just trying to copy the input to the output... do a Google search for "XSL identity template".

Answer (score 3):

Your `??????????????????` can be `<xsl:value-of select="."/>` (i.e. the string-value of the context element.)  It has no connection to `$elementName`.

You can do this much more succinctly like this:

```
<xsl:for-each select="*">
  <xsl:variable name="elementName" select="name()"/>
  <xsl:variable name="elementValue" select="string(.)"/>
</xsl:for-each>
```

However your template is really strange.  You're collecting these variables but you're not doing anything with them--they won't appear in the output. What output are you trying to get?

Use of `for-each` is generally a code smell. In almost all cases you're better off with multiple templates:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" encoding="utf-8" omit-xml-declaration="no" />

<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Person/*">
    <xsl:variable name="elementName" select="name()"/>
    <xsl:variable name="elementValue" select="string(.)"/>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This pattern where you copy almost everything and change just a little bit of the xml is very common and very powerful and you should [learn how to use it](http://xmlplease.com/xsltidentity).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This is not full xsl. Actually I need to modify the xml according to the values in the elements.

Comment: Have you considered using templates instead of nested `for-each` loops?

Comment: I am new in xsl. Don't know much about using templates.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you really wanted to get the value of an element whose name is held in a variable, in your case you would do it like this

```
<xsl:variable name="elementValue">
    <xsl:value-of select="../*[name()=$elementName]" />
</xsl:variable>
```

But, this is greatly overcomplicated matters. You are in a **xsl:for-each** loop, iterating over the child elements of a **Person**. Therefore, because you are already positioned on the element for which you want the value, you can just do this and forget about the **elementName** variable.

```
<xsl:variable name="elementValue">
    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
</xsl:variable>
```

In fact, in you could simplify your loops to just this

```
<xsl:for-each select="PersonList/Person">
   <Person>
      <xsl:for-each select="*">
         <xsl:value-of select="." />
      </xsl:for-each>
   </Person>
</xsl:for-each>
```